# How to "getSelectedOption" from carousel on Dialogflow JSON Fulfilment V2

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am working with DialogFlow , I created a **carousel** on My Welcome-Intent, then I created a `actions_intent_OPTION` to get the Option on fulfilment.

the thing is.. I cant get this carousel selected option... How can I get the option in JSON? This is my function:

```
'carrousel': () => {
    let responseToUser = {
          fulfillmentText: 'Your Option was.. ' + option // displayed response
        };
        sendResponse(responseToUser);
    },
```

and I am trying to get the carousel selected Option like this but the response is `UNSPECIFIED`

```
var option = request.body.queryResult.parameters.tipo;
```

[image]

Comment: did you set the variable with same name in Actions and Parameters as `tipo`?

Comment: No o: ,I tried to send it on a follow UP intent but i can"t. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using DialogFlow you might be able to simply do:

```
app.intent('actions.intent.OPTION', (conv, params, option) => {
//Whatever you want to do with the option }
```

The option parameter will be what's selected by the user. There's more detail on the [Response Documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#carousel).

(I use Firebase hosted code, and this approach works for me.)

If you need it from the raw JSON, you seem to have to dig deeper into the request. From what I could tell when trying to access it, the user's selected option is under:

```
request.body.queryResult.outputContexts
```

From there it goes into a list with all previously set contexts. If you get the right context (which will be `actions_intent_option`), you should then be able to access the option by selecting:

```
.parameters.OPTION
```